# How do I add a secret file to my Docker build Github Action?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

According to [this page](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/secrets/) it seems like it is possible to use a file as an action secret.

My repo has an untracked file full of config that I would like to keep untracked, but is still needed as part of the docker build process. Ideally I would add this file as a secret and include it in my Github Action.

I am new to docker and Github Actions as well, so if this is possible I have not figured out how.

So far I have only tried using non-file secrets as part of my Github Action which has worked, but without this config file the entire Action is pretty much pointless.

Comment: What have you tried and what's not working? Please include that in your question.

Comment: @Azeem I haven't really tried anything, I'm just trying to figure out of this is even possible to do.

Comment: Well, you have to try that first. If something's not working, edit and update your question with that specific problem along with its respective workflow.